# How to mark the Employee with highest salary with * ? - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem - here is my `Employee` table:

```
Name  | Department  | Salary
------+-------------+-------------
Ram   |IT           |  1000    
Shyam |HR           |  2000    
Sita  |Management   |  5000  
Joe   |IT           |  6000    
Lacy  |HR           |  2000    
Gen   |Management   |  4000  
Maria |IT           |  2000    
Antony|HR           |  3000    
Raman |Management   |  50000
```

Now I want the result like this:

```
Department   |   Salary   |
-------------+------------+    
IT           |  20000    
HR           |  30000    
Management   |  50000     |  *
```

Where `*` will be used to mark the max salary from any department. I've tried many unsucessful attempts, like :

```
Select 
    Salary,
    Case 
       When Salary = Max(Salary) Then '*' 
    End 
From 
    tblEmployees 
Group By 
    Salary
```

Comment: Are the columns in your Employee table correct?  Looks like Salary and Department are flipped.

Comment: Your desired results don't add up from the sample data.   It is unclear whether you want the highest single employee in each department, or the sum of all employees in each department.

Comment: @ParrishHusband First one is the table and second is the result.

Comment: @TabAlleman It's the sum of all employees in each department.

Comment: @Deepak but you accepted an answer that doesn't involve a sum of all the employees in the department.   It only gets the highest single employee in each department.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a window function:

```
Select Department, max(Salary) as salary,
       (case When max(Salary) = max(Max(Salary)) over ()
             Then '*' 
        End)
from tblEmployees
group by department;
```

Answer (score 1):

The IT department in your result should be 6000.

```
select Department,
       salary =         max_sal_dep,
       highest_salary = IIF(max_sal_dep = max_sal_all, '*', null)
from
(
    select Department,
           max_sal_all = MAX(Salary) over (),
           max_sal_dep = MAX(Salary) over (partition by Department order by Department),
           the_row = row_number () over (partition by Department order by Salary desc)
    from @t
) x where x.the_row = 1
order by x.max_sal_dep;
```